# How to convert VB6 code to C# for MailMerge operation?

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6, vb6-migration, mailmerge

I'm trying to convert the below VB6 code into C# but as expected am having some issues. Can anyone help me out? This is my first time attempting to code with a MailMerge document. Even some help getting the `oWord` object set-up should get me going I think. I've managed to get the ListView control of my C# Windows Forms application filled with data by querying the 400 system through an ODBC connection, now I need to use this data to execute a MailMerge document.

```
Dim oWD As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
oDoc.MailMerge.Execute

Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
oWord.Visible = False
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(docpath & docname & ".doc")

 oWord.ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False
 oWord.ActiveDocument.Saved = True
 oWord.ActiveDocument.Close
 oWord.Windows(1).Activate
 oWord.ActiveDocument.Saved = True
 oWord.ActiveDocument.Close
 oWord.Quit (wdDoNotSaveChanges)

Public Sub CommitGroup(ByVal FileSys As String)

   Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
   oWord.Visible = False
   Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(docpath & docname & ".doc")

   For i = 1 To counter

     oWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = i
     oWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = i

     If FileSys = "NAI" Or FileSys = "NTM" Or FileSys = "PAI" Or FileSys = "PTM" Then
       idx1 = Format(oWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields.Item(4).Value, "000000")
       idx2 = ""
       idx3 = ""
       FYIDocName = UCase(Mid(FileSys, 1, 1)) & "%" & idx1 & "%" & idx2 & "%" & idx3 & _
                   "%CORRESPONDENCE%OUTGOING - ACKNOWLEDGEMENT%" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss") & "BATCH" & i
     Else
       idx1 = Format(oWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields.Item(21).Value, "000000")
       idx2 = oWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields.Item(4).Value
       idx3 = Format(oWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields.Item(5).Value, "000000")
       FYIDocName = UCase(Mid(FileSys, 1, 1)) & "%" & idx1 & "%" & idx2 & "%" & idx3 & _
                   "%CORRESPONDENCE%OUTGOING - ACKNOWLEDGEMENT%" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss") & "BATCH" & i
     End If
     oWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Execute

     oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="c:\temp\to fyi\" & Trim(FYIDocName) & "BATCH.doc"
     oWord.ActiveDocument.Close
     oWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextDataSourceRecord
   Next


oWord.Quit (wdDoNotSaveChanges)

End Sub
```

Comment: in C# you would create an COM object with "Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.application"));"

Comment: You might find this helpful: [How to automate Microsoft Word to perform Mail Merge from Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301659)